# Linq-to-Objects Where clause with 2 predicates

Tags: linq-to-objects

Is it better to have 2 Where clauses or 1 Where clause with && operator or does it not matter?

```
list.Where(x => x.Prop1 == value1).Where(x => x.Prop2 == value2).ToList();
```

Or

```
list.Where(x => x.Prop1 == value1 && x.Prop2 == value2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use the second with two tests in a single lambda. It will loop the list only once and call a delegate only half as often. The first version loops the list twice.

Just to be clear, this is the better option:

```
list.Where(x => x.Prop1 == value1 && x.Prop2 == value2).ToList();
```

Which can also be written

```
var results =
   (from x in list
   where x.Prop1 == value1 && x.Prop2 == value2
   select x).ToList();
```

If you can avoid the `.ToList()` call and use it as an `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll usually get even better perf (unless you read it over and over).

Comment: @Jon and Michael, the first version does not loop over the list twice. There will be two delegates, yes, but the checks are performed one after the other for each element in the sequence, it is not a case of the entire sequence going through the first *followed by* the results going through the second. The list is only walked once.

Comment: and Jon, with that said, I agree that I would opt for the second version.